# Gradle - specifying configuration based dependency

Tags: gradle

While reading [this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html#sec:listing_dependencies) `gradle` document, I came across this wordings saying that **`dependencies for each configuration`**. Here what does this **`configuration`** meant to be. Because I usually used to specify the dependencies in such a vague way like

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.5.RELEASE',
            'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:3.6.7.Final'
}
```

Is there any other possible way to specify the dependencies(**based on configuration**)?. I am little curious to know about that.

If yes, what is advantage of specifying dependencies like that. Can someone able to throw some light here?

Also how the below command will be useful?

```
gradle -q dependencies api:dependencies webapp:dependencies
```

Comment: If you're coming from the maven world, gradle configurations have some similarity with maven scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Gradle dependencies are grouped into configurations. Configurations have a name, a number of other properties, and they can extend each other. Many Gradle plugins add pre-defined configurations to your project.

[These](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management) are the configurations added by Java plugin. As you can see, `compile` is a configuration, it is extended by many other configurations. You can create your own configuration:

```
configurations {
    myConfig {
        description = 'my config'
        transitive = true
        extendsFrom compile
    }
}
```

> Also how the below command will be useful?

This command prints the dependencies of main project and `api` and `webapp` subprojects.

Comment: Can you explain me the advantages of having `dependencies for each configuration` over declaring dependencies in normal way?

Comment: Ok, I got some basic idea from https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#configurations